# Underlining links with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

My theme's css file has a typical line written out for links to the effect of

```
a { 
text-decoration: none; 
}
```

so that none of the links on my site are underlined. It originally had the text decoration set to be underlined, but because items like my blog post titles and "more text" links were all being underlined, I set the text decor to none. I'm wondering, is there a way to go about underlining my in-post links (for example when I'm referring to another article or webpage in a blog post) without having to edit every other element in my css file by adding text-decoration to "none !important" ?

Comment: You just need to add another class, like `post_link` for the links you want underlined. Then in the HTML, `<a class="post_link"...>` and in the CSS, `a.post_link { text-decoration: underline; }` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you! So when you say add another class, would I simply just add to the a.post_link line you wrote up to my css file? And then refer to it with the HTML code in my blog post?

Comment: Yes. You should Google "CSS tutorial" to learn the basics of CSS. This is a very basic kind of problem which CSS solves.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your HTML and find an element which consistently contains all those and only those links you want to underline, for instance

```
<div class="blogpost"> 
  ... 
  I just found <a href="http://example.com">this amazing site</a>!
  ...
</div>
```

Then use the descendant selector (space) to select the links inside:

```
 .blogpost a { text-decoration: underline }
```